# R:missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I am trying to assign letters to the column before drawing the dandrogram. Here is the code>

```
data<-data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4),Y=c(1,3,2,1))
dataset1<-as.data.frame(as.matrix( dist(data)))
colnames(dataset1) <- c("A","B","C","D")
rownames(dataset1) <- c("A","B","C","D")
plot(hclust(dataset1, method = "single"))
```

but in the last line it complains with>

```
Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance matrix contains only 3 rows and 3 columns. Easier to just put the labels in the row.names of the data.frame and plot the dendogram.

```
df <- data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4),Y=c(1,3,2,1), row.names=c("A","B","C","D"))
plot(hclust(dist(df)))
```

[image]

Comment: and then the result of dataframe would be in what object?

Comment: `could not find function "%>%"`

Comment: The %>% is a magrittr pipe that is loaded with dplyr.